# Exclude constraintlayout dependency from gradle

Tags: android, gradle, stripe-payments

I am using the `StripeSDK`, and I want to exclude the constraintlayout library that is embedded within their `SDK`. How can I exclude the constraintlayout from being merged into my app? I am using a slightly older version, and upgrading is causing a visual glitch.

I tried:

```
implementation ('com.stripe:stripe-android:16.10.0') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout'
}
```

also tried:

```
implementation ('com.stripe:stripe-android:16.10.0') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout' module:'app'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to this is not to exclude the group, but to force the version you want to use as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62278010/1076562

> When Gradle encounters two different versions of the same dependency,
> it will perform a conflict resolution. It defaults to choosing the
> highest version number.
>
> However, because many libraries like Jackson consists of a number of
> individual modules like `jackson-databind` and `jackson-core`, you may end
> up in a situation where there is a mismatch between the different
> versions.
>
> To align them, you can use the Jackson BOM and Gradle's [platform
> dependency](https://blog.gradle.org/alignment-with-gradle-module-metadata) mechanism. It looks like this (choose only one of the
> depencendies below):
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     // Enforce the specified version  
>     implementation(enforcedPlatform("com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.10.4"))
>
>     // Align all modules to the same version, but allow upgrade to a higher version  
>     implementation(platform("com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.10.4"))
> }
> ```
>
> You don't need to exclude anything from your other dependencies.